# Will Martin-Löf Type Theory lead to a greater ability to write provably correct code?

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, type-theory, automated-theorem-proving

[This post](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/11/11/unifying-programming-and-math-the-dependent-type-revolution/) refers to the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) and the [Martin-Löf Type Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin-L%C3%B6f_type_theory).

The post makes the claim of a future 'unification' between the the describing language of math, and the operation based language of computer programming.

My questions are:

1. Will these ideas lead to a better ability (through languages) to write provably correct code?
2. Have the full implications of MLTT been discovered on a theoretical level?
3. Does this post describe anything could couldn't already do in COQ or Agda?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think your question is particularly well posed. It mostly asks for opinions. Here are mine:

1. Yes.
2. I do not know what you mean, but the answer is probably "there is more MLTT theory to be done, although we do know a lot".
3. You cannot do all of homotopy type theory in Coq and Agda. This is an active area of research.

Comment: Ok - how would you have phrased questions relating to the original post?

Comment: I don't know because I do not understand what the question is asking. The second question is too broad, and the obvious answer is "no". The third question is ok, I suppose. The first question asks us to predict the future.